# How to stop messages in spring-integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Is it possible to stop the distribution of messages in the middle of the pipeline?
I have many endpoints where further distribution of the message may become unnecessary. I understand that it is possible to use routers. Can this somehow be avoided, otherwise the pipeline will be very cumbersome?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What have you tried so far? Why simple `stop()` on an endpoint doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thanx for reply. I need to stop not the endpoint, but the propagation of some (more unnecessary) messages.

Comment: Then see `Fitler` EI pattern: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#filter

Comment: You have to be much clear with your description. You see some people may even answer to you with wrong way... Also you don't react to answers at all: that's a bit out of the policy here on SO...

Comment: Thanks a lot for a suitable help! I'll be more correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use NullChannel to drop the message. Have a look at https://dzone.com/articles/message-processing-spring